# Unload specific UITableViewCells

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Is there a way to unload/release a `UITableViewCell` such that the containing UITableView calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when it is needed again?

I understand that this is exactly what `UITableView` does by default, but **only** once the cells are outside the tableview frame. My custom view uses `UITableView` in such a way that its frame == content size.

If there is no way to unload specific cells, I'll have to think of a different approach.

Comment: Won't `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` fit your needs to reload specific rows? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

Comment: I don't want to reload them, I want to unload them... the tableview is  partly off-screen and I want to unload cells that are off-screen.

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. But it does not matter. You should be leaving the unloading of cells to iOS. If your approach requires your control over this process, you should proceed with thinking about different approaches. If you tell us what problem you're trying to solve (as I can't imagine why you need to do this), I'm sure we can propose solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The method `[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]` allows you to tell the table view to reload one or more cells. This will reload the specified cell(s) if they are on screen and presumably do nothing if they aren't currently on screen. Sounds like what you want though your question is not entirely clear to me.